Present a message in a form label letter by letter with delay time of less than one second
I have a label which I want to present a message on so it will write it letter after letter.
This writes the first letter of Msg and then gets stuck.
I played with the delay time but it doesn’t help.
Private Sub ShowEvent (Msg As String)
Dim X As Integer
    
For X = 1 To Len (Msg)
    
    EventsDesc.Caption= Left (MSG, x)
    
    Application.Wait (Now+TimeValue ("00:00:01"))
    
Next X
    
End Sub


Could we see the code you've tried?  I take it you're using VBA for this.

Hi I added a photo of the code

https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Hi I’m using a private network so I couldn’t copy the code but I’ll write it here

Try Adding DoEvents after the Application.Wait line.

Yeah it worked thanks!!!!

Do you have an idea how I make it wait less than a second?

No idea why this was closed.  Voted to re-open.

Use the Timer function to calculate times less than a second along with DoEvents to pass control to the operating system.
I found 0.1 is fast enough that the user won't get bored waiting for the label to populate.
Private Sub ShowEvent(Msg As String)

    Dim X As Integer
    Dim t As Double
    
    For X = 1 To Len(Msg)
        
        EventsDesc.Caption = Left(Msg, X)
        
        t = Timer
        Do Until Timer - t >= 0.1
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
    Next X

End Sub

